# can I concatenate a piece of code from some source and execute it with Google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

```js
                                                                                       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
var sourceValue = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var source = sourceValue[0][0];

Logger.log(source);

FUNC_CONTENT_TO_INJECT = source;

function main() {
  var a,functionContent,objectOfData,x;

  functionContent = "new " + FUNC_CONTENT_TO_INJECT;

  objectOfData = {};//Create new empty object

  a = "Test Value";
  x = "Hello World";

  objectOfData["a"] = a;//Add a key / value pair to the object
  objectOfData["x"] = x;

  new Function("o", functionContent).call("",objectOfData);
};
```

Hi I have created an Adwords script and it runs perfectly.
Is there a way that my code will be inside a spreadsheet and let the main script run this piece of code and execute it?

the reason I'm doing it is because I don't want any body to read/copy my script and I don't have any other solution for now. It will look something like that :

```js
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xr3FIVoctvBTyR6N-MILpbqSmMuyd2pvEzO86BuHsK4/');
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var sourceValues = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var source = sourceValues[0][0]
  
  //this is where I want to concatenate my code 
  + source
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* possible to use function content outside of an Apps Script project and inject it into your Apps Script code.  Function content can be retrieved, a new function created with that function content and then the new function run with no trace of the code left behind after it has completed.  You can prove it to yourself with the following code:

```
var FUNC_CONTENT_TO_INJECT;//Define a global variable without assigning a value

//Assign a value to the global variable
FUNC_CONTENT_TO_INJECT = "function injectedFunction() {Logger.log('x: ' + x);" +
                         "Logger.log('a: ' + a)}";

function main() {
  var a,x,functionContent;

  functionContent = "new " + FUNC_CONTENT_TO_INJECT;

  a = "Test Value";
  x = "Hello World";

  new Function("a,x", functionContent).call("",a,x);
};
```

By using the "new" keyword, a temporary function can be created and then immediately called with `call()`

[Mozilla Documentation - JavaScript call() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

In the example above, I've entered an empty string as the first parameter in the `call()` method.  The first parameter is treated differently than all subsequent parameters.  All subsequent parameters after the first are treated as individual variables.  The first parameter is the `thisArg`  It is related to the `this` keyword and the scope.

```
function.call(thisArg,value1, value2,etc)
```

Also in the example above, I used a GLOBAL variable to simulate the function content that you would be getting from the spreadsheet.

I would advise adding some kind of conditional test to determine if the function content coming in is from you.  Any function content, from any source could be injected, and the code would run as long as it can be processed as valid code.  Because your `main()` function is not receiving any input parameters, and the function content is coming from a spreadsheet with a specific ID that is owned by you, I don't know how anyone would inject some other function content into the code.  But, taking some simple precautions can't hurt.  The situation you would need to worry about more, is a server function being called from a Web App where data could be sent from the client's browser to the function.

```
var FUNC_CONTENT_TO_INJECT;

FUNC_CONTENT_TO_INJECT = "function injectedFunction() {Logger.log(o);" +
  "Logger.log('typeof o: ' + typeof o);" +
  "Logger.log('x: ' + o.x);" +
                         "Logger.log('a: ' + o.a)}";

function main() {
  var a,functionContent,objectOfData,x;

  functionContent = "new " + FUNC_CONTENT_TO_INJECT;

  objectOfData = {};//Create new empty object

  a = "Test Value";
  x = "Hello World";

  objectOfData["a"] = a;//Add a key / value pair to the object
  objectOfData["x"] = x;

  new Function("o", functionContent).call("",objectOfData);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. what if my function is a little more complicated than processing 2 variables? I have tried to adjust the idea to my needs but it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: You can create an object of variables, so that you would only have one parameter, and all the data is inside an object.  The object will then have any amount of variables in it. JSON object ->  `{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", etc}`  See updated answer with new code at bottom.

Comment: so it is working when I type the function as a global variable but when I tried to read it from a variable I get error which says that the function is a string.. any idea why and can I solve this?

Comment: If you can create a relatively simple example that produces the error, I can try to reproduce it.  Also, if you can print the variable value to the Log with `Logger.log('variableName: ' + variableName)` and then post the result that would help.  Also, the `new` keyword is used twice.  In my example the word "new" is concatenated to the front of the string.